# Заявка не отправляется из Contact Form 7?

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress и форма. Если хочу отправить до заполнения - показывает ошибку, т.е проходит валидацию. Но когда все заполнено правильно и нажимаю отправку, бесконечно грузится ajax loader. Типа отправляется... Не могу понять в чем ошибка, ибо ошибок в коде нет(

Comment: Поставьте CF7 версии 4.7 и сбросьте кеши.

Comment: См ошибки в консоли браузера и логи на сервере.